# React native create library which uses cocapods

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I want to create a react-native library which uses cocapods. This library is dependant on Alamofire using Pods file.  When I compile the library project (.xcworkspace), it builds fine. But when I link the library's projects `.xcodeproj` file to my react-native app. When running the project, the build fails complaining the Alamofire module is not found.

So my question is, how can I link a library which uses cocapods in my react-native project which also uses cocapods for dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a `Podfile` in your `iOS` folder, then when you link a project that has a `.podspec` file in their folder it will try to use the pods from that node_module. I've found that installing the pod file that iOS would use natively has worked better. For example, I use `react-native-fbsdk` and instead of referencing the node_module I've installed

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.0'
```

Another thing you could do, assuming you don't want to link using cocoapods, you'd just have to manually link the [libraries](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking). Hope this helps!